# callfunc in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

In cocos2d-x, the following piece of code is supposed to run the callback function after a delay. What do I need to do to fix the error?

```
bool LoadingLevelScreen::initialise() {

        // set up the time delay
    CCDelayTime *delayAction = CCDelayTime::actionWithDuration(0.5f);

    // perform the selector call
    CCCallFunc *callSelectorAction = CCCallFunc::actionWithTarget( 
        this, callfunc_selector( LoadingLevelScreen::menuCallbackStart ) );

    // run the action
    this->runAction( CCSequence::actions(
        delayAction, callSelectorAction, NULL ) );
}

void LoadingLevelScreen::menuCallbackStart(CCObject * pSender)
{
}
```

Compiler Error:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : 
cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall LoadingLevelScreen::* )(cocos2d::CCObject *)' 
to 'cocos2d::SEL_CallFunc'
Pointers to members have different representations; cannot cast between them
```

Comment: I can tell you that specifying LoadingLevelScreen:: makes it a pointer to a static function, but the function's not declared static. It's been a while since I used C++ so I'm not 100% sure, I think it should be: callfunc_selector( this->menuCallbackStart )

Comment: Thx, but that does not solve the problem: `error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression`.

Comment: Also, all the menu item selectors work this way without any problems, e.g. `CCMenuItemLabel* itmStart = CCMenuItemLabel::itemWithLabel(
   lblStart, this, menu_selector(LoadingLevelScreen::menuCallbackItem) );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either remove the `CCObject*` parameter in `menuCallbackStart()` method (because `CCCallFunc::actionWithTarget()` expects a method with no arguments), or change `CCCallFunc` to `CCCallFuncO` which expects a method with a `CCObject*` as argument, like so:

```
CCCallFuncO * callSelectorAction =
    CCCallFuncO::create(this, &LoadingLevelScreen::menuCallbackStart, myObject);
```

where `myObject` is a `CCObject *` that will be passed to your method as the argument.

Note that `callfunc_selector()` is just a macro that typecasts your method to `SEL_CallFunc`:

```
#define callfunc_selector(MYSELECTOR) (SEL_CallFunc)(& (MYSELECTOR))
```

BTW `::actionWithTarget()` is being deprecated, so use `::create()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful :) And that little "BTW" helped me to resolve a bunch of "deprecated" warnings by replacing various function calls with create().

Answer (score 3):

```
void LoadingLevelScreen::menuCallbackStart(CCObject * pSender)
{
}
```

should be

```
void LoadingLevelScreen::menuCallbackStart()
{
}
```

callfunc_selector is different with menu_selector, you don't need the CCObject* to pass in as a variable

if you do need to pass argument, please use callFuncND

Answer (score 1):

this->runAction(Sequence::create(CallFunc::create(std::bind(&CNm::MNm, this)),NULL));

Answer (score 0):

this->runAction(Sequence::create(CallFunc::create(std::bind(&ClassName::MethodName, this)),NULL));